# Can you make xfce panel applet using python?

Tags: python, xfce

Is it possible to make a xfce panel applet using python? Most if not all panel applets seem to use C so I doubt that I would able to.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Check for example [XFCE-PANEL-PLUGIN development using Python/Javascript](https://freshlybuilt.com/xfce-panel-plugin-development-using-python-javascript-part-1/)

This is an example for GtkSocket and GtkPlug:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
General flow of program
Entry widget -> GtkPlug -> GtkSocket -> Window
"""

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys


def perform_embed_event(widget):
    print("This will get called when plug will emit embedded signal")

# initialize GtkWindow
window = Gtk.Window()

# initialize GtkSocket
socket = Gtk.Socket()

# store socket id in socket_id variable
socket_id = socket.get_id()

print("socket", socket_id)

window.add(socket)
window.show()

# initialize GtkPlug
plug = Gtk.Plug.new(socket_id)

# Different Plug signals
plug.connect("embedded", perform_embed_event)
plug.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

print("Plug ID:", plug.get_id())

# Entry Widget
entry = Gtk.Entry()
entry.set_text("Xfce GSoC 2021")

# Add entry widget into plug
plug.add(entry)

plug.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```